# Repeating horizontal auto scroll bar

Tags: javascript, scroll

i have an auto scrolling bar script that makes the images scroll right. I want to make it repeat after reaching the end. Please help!

```html
<div class="scrolls">
    <div>
        <img src="img1" height="200"/>
        <img src="img2" height="200"/>
        <img src="img3" height="200"/>
    </div>          
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var sL = 4000;
        $('.scrolls').animate({
            scrollLeft : sL
        },100000, 'linear');

        $(".scrolls").on("click",function(){
                $(this).stop(true,false);
        });

        $(".scrolls").on("mouseenter",function(){
            $(this).stop(true,false);
        });

        $(".scrolls").on("mouseleave",function(){
            $(this).animate({
            scrollLeft : sL
            },100000, 'linear');
        });
    })
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take an unordered list with listitems (html markup)

```
<div class="scrolls">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="img1" height="200"/></li>
        <li><img src="img2" height="200"/></li>
        <li><img src="img3" height="200"/></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Copy this listitems so you can fillup the whole horizontal space twice. Now scroll the div to the right and everytime an image leaves the div to the left, move it from the beginning to the end.

```
// create as many copys as needed for filling the whole harizontal space twice
var dummyClones = $('.scrolls > ul > li').clone(true);
while($('.scrolls > ul').width() < 2*$('.scrolls').width())
  $('.scrolls > ul').append(dummyClones.clone(true));
```

The animation itself is solved through `window.requestAnimationFrame`:

```
var animationSpeedInMiliseconds = 10000; // 10 seconds for 1000px
function step(timestamp) {
    if(!step.startTimestamp) step.startTimestamp = timestamp;
    if(!step.stopped) {
        let delta = timestamp - step.startTimestamp;
        let pixelCountToShift = (delta / animationSpeedInMiliseconds) * 1000;
        if($('.scrolls').scrollLeft()+pixelCountToShift > $('.scrolls > ul > li:eq(0)').width()) {
            $('.scrolls > ul').append($('.scrolls > ul > li:eq(0)'));
            $('.scrolls').scrollLeft($('.scrolls').scrollLeft()+pixelCountToShift-$('.scrolls > ul > li:eq(0)').width());
        } else {
            $('.scrolls').scrollLeft($('.scrolls').scrollLeft()+pixelCountToShift);
        }
    }
    step.startTimestamp = timestamp;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
}
```

**Attention: It's not perfect. It's an example I created in 4 minutes and it's meant to be understood as an proof-of-concept. Not a script for productional use.**

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Kasalop/tktfr4rz/2/

Comment: Please try using Snippets were possible.

Comment: @Keith Not a fan of snippets (my browser security policy blocks them anyway) but I promise that I will keep busy with snippets in the future.